# Wildcard search on Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Im creating a macro in excel that has search function. so basically. i will put the list of servers in Sheet3 Column A and it will search the servers ing Sheet1 column A. Once done, it will display the result in Sheet 2 column A. However, im having issue in searching for wildcard. for example. i want to seach server "ABC123" but it will not display the result because it needs to be the whole name of the server "ABC123.def" can anyone help me with the codes?

```
    Option Explicit
Sub HostNameFinder()
Dim srchLen, hName, nxtRw As String
Dim g As Range
'Clear Sheet 2 and Copy Column Headings
 Sheets(2).Cells.ClearContents
 Sheets(1).Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Rows(1)
'Determine length of Search Column from Sheet3
   srchLen = Sheets(3).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'Loop through list in Sheet3, Column A. As each value is 'found in Sheet1, Column A, copy it top the next row in Sheet2
  With Sheets(1).Columns("A")
    For hName = 2 To srchLen
      Set g = .Find(Sheets(3).Range("A" & hName), lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not g Is Nothing Then
          nxtRw = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
          g.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("A" & nxtRw)
        End If
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you fire up the macro recorder and perform a search for "ABC123" with the option to look in formulas and the option "Match entire cell contents" NOT selected, Excel will find the cell with the value ABC123.def

You could then study the code created by the macro recorder and would notice the difference to your code. You use `lookat:=xlWhole`, i.e. you're looking at the whole cell. Change it to `LookAt:=xlPart`. This is the equivalent of using a wildcard.

Or build the search term by wrapping it in a set of asterisks.

```
 Set g = .Find("*" & Sheets(3).Range("A" & hName) & "*", lookat:=xlWhole)
```